# How to fill in shape made with brush tool Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, brush, fill

I would like to make a complex shape using the brush tool and then use stroke and fills to create color.

I started with one shape made from 8 brush strokes

I selected all of the strokes with the direct selection tool

I am left with a fill that looks like this:

[image: I am left with a fill that looks like this]

I've tried grouping the brush strokes (right click-group) first with little difference. I've tried converting my shape into a vector (expand appearance) and then applying the fill but Illustrator maintains no fill to the object.

Note: this picture is just an example. The real problem is in a much larger piece that does not lend itself well to the pen tool.

Comment: Can you show us what your shape looked like before?

Comment: @Ambo100 http://imgur.com/a/AZ4nH

Comment: I think you may find your answer here: [How to fill in areas surrounded by line segments?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29029/how-to-fill-in-areas-surrounded-by-line-segments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question … Maybe try using the [Live Paint Bucket](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/live-paint-groups.html) and [Shaper](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/building-new-shapes-using-shape.html#about_the_shaper_tool) Tools.

1. **Draw you shape with brush tool:**

   [image]
2. **Select all the overlapping lines and click with Live Paint Bucket tool:**

   [image]

   Use your arrow keys to select a swatch color and click in the middle of your shape to fill with chosen color.
3. **Use the Shaper tool to clean up your leftover lines:**

   [image]
4. Finally, optionally, **expand the shape to get full control over stroke and fill:**

   [image]

---

Another way could be to **use the “Pathfinder effects” found in the [Pathfinder palette](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html)**. For example, here’s “Divide” in action:

[image]

YMMV. :)

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped. :) Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the above picture you've shared, it could also help to **join** the paths and create a single path which you can fill pretty easy.